# Rails - Pundit - resolve method not operating correctly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pundit

I am trying to figure out how to use pundit with my rails 4 app.

I have an article policy and an article index view.

In the article policy, I have a resolve method which has scopes for different types of users.

```
def resolve
    if user == @user.id
        scope.all.where(user_id: user.id)
    elsif user.has_role?(:org_approver)
        scope.to_be_reviewed
    else
        scope.in_state(:publish)
    end     
end
```

In my index show, I'm expecting to show each user the articles in the array depending on which category they fit into within my resolve method.

```
<% policy_scope(Article).sort_by(&:created_at).in_groups_of(2) do |group| %>
    <div id="portfolioFiltering" class="masonry-wrapper row">
         <% group.compact.each do |article| %>
         <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-1 portfolioitem Scienza">
         <div class="portfolio-item text-
```

I don't get any errors, but when I login as the user that is the author of the article, I expect to get all of the articles belonging to me (as that user). Instead, I get all the published articles, only (which is the last alternative in my resolve method).

Can anyone see where I've gone wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this line is the problem:

```
user == @user.id
```

it should be:

```
user == @user
```

Because a `User` object will never be equal to an `Integer` object, which is what you get when you call `id` on a `User` object.

Also, take a look at [Pundit GitHub page](https://github.com/elabs/pundit) and scroll down to the RSpec section on testing. **You should always test authentication and authorization.**